# How do I install php5 via MacPorts with a custom configure option?

Tags: php, macports

So MacPorts is the most painless way of installing stuff on my machine. But I want some custom options on my php5 install. How do I do this?

With a downloaded version of php, I would do this:
./php_folder/configure --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d

With MacPorts I install it with this:
sudo port install php5 +apache2 +mysql5 +pear

But I want to do something like this...
sudo port install php5 +apache2 +mysql5 +pear --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d

I just have no idea how to do it. Documentation says I can create a portfile but that looks a bit overkill for what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can try go to /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/ subfolder and open in pico or vim editor `Portfile` located in each product folder you want to install.

For example - `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/lang/php5/Portfile`

In this file you should go to line with text `configure.args` and add configure options you need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Customizing the Portfile is the right way to go, as suggested by [Dmitry](https://superuser.com/a/400960/289256). But instead of messing with the official portfile synced from rsync.macports.org, it might be a better idea to create a [local portfile repository](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories) and put the customized version of the portfile there.